# How to get the ISA06 Interchange Sender ID of an FTP transfer in debian linux

Tags: linux, curl, ftp, debian, instruction-set

I have been following a trail of breadcrumbs for a couple days now. My company is needing a simple API/EDI built that can communicate with a bunch of different marketplaces. One of them requires I give them the ISA Interchange Sender ID to even make FTP requests to their server.
     Here is a link to a page enumerating on what exactly is ISA06, in x12 ANSI. Relevant content copied and pasted from the site.

```
  The ISA Segment has the following structure
    ISA01 Authorization Information Qualifier : min/max – 2/2
    ISA02 Authorization Information : min/max – 10/10
    ISA03 Security Information Qualifier : min/max – 2/2
    ISA04 Security Information : min/max – 10/10
    ISA05 Interchange ID Qualifier : min/max – 2/2
    ISA06 Interchange Sender ID : min/max – 15/15
    ISA07 Interchange ID Qualifier : min/max – 2/2
    ISA08 Interchange Receiver ID : min/max – 15/15
    ISA09 Interchange Date : min/max – 6/6
    ISA10 Interchange Time : min/max – 4/4
    ISA11 Interchange Control Standards ID : min/max – 1/1
    ISA12 Interchange Control Version Number : min/max – 5/5
    ISA13 Interchange Control Number : min/max – 9/9
    ISA14 Acknowledgment Requested : min/max – 1/1
    ISA15 Test Indicator : min/max – 1/1
    ISA16 Subelement Separator : min/max – 1/1
```

Link to full page: http://edicrossroad.blogspot.com/2008/12/isa-and-gs-segment-elements-enumeration.html

I can't find any information on how to inspect the entire request in plain txt format. It needs to be FTP but even a curl function would be great right about now and put me on track. The regular curl_getinfo function does not go into enough detail to even mention ISA at all.

I do see a bunch of different proprietary parsers that you can buy a license for, but it's overkill for our needs (which is just to transfer a couple .csv files with FTP to update information with the marketplace once a day)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive had some luck with EDI.Net (open sourced) and EdiFabric (closed source). Both are excellent libraries for generating and receiving feeds like the above. For manual work, X12 Studio is good for beginners but I personally like to use Sublime.

Here is a collection of tools if you are looking for something else: https://github.com/michaelachrisco/Electronic-Interchange-Github-Resources